# Type of "succ(zero)" differs from type of "one" in GHC

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, lambda-calculus

Asking the GHC to print the type of "one" and "succ zero" (lambda calculus way of encoding numerals), I get two different types!
Shouldn't they be the same?
Can you also show me how to derive its type manually?

```
zero = \ f x -> x
one = \ f x -> f x
succ = \ n f x -> f (n (f x))

:t one -- (t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t2

:t succ zero -- ((t1 -> t1) -> t2) -> (t1 -> t1) -> t2
```

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Calculation_with_Church_numerals), it should be `f (n f x)`, not `f (n (f x))`

Comment: The way to think of a church numeral `n` is that it is a function of two arguments. `n f x` applies `f` to `x` `n` times. So if `n` is supposed to represent 3 then `n f x` evaluates to `f (f (f x))`.  Anyway, thought that might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as was said in the comments, the correct definition is

```
zero   f x = x
succ n f x = f (n f x)
```

> *"do one more `f` after `n` applications of `f`, starting with `x`."*

Thus

```
one f x = succ zero f x = f (zero f x) = f x
two f x = succ one  f x = f (one  f x) = f (f x)
```

The types which get derived are more general initially,

```
zero     ::     t      -> t1 -> t1     -- most general
one      :: (t1 -> t ) -> t1 -> t      -- less general
succ one :: (t2 -> t2) -> t2 -> t2     -- most specific
```

but it doesn't matter, they all match (unify) between themselves, and starting from `two = succ one` the type settles down into the most specific `(b -> b) -> (b -> b)`.

You could also define

```
church :: Int -> (b -> b) -> b -> b           -- is derived so by GHCi
church n f x = foldr ($) x (replicate n f)
             = foldr (.) id (replicate n f) x
{- church n  = foldr (.) id . replicate n     -- (^ n) for functions -}
```

and have all types be exactly the same, as

```
church 0 :: (b -> b) -> b -> b
church 1 :: (b -> b) -> b -> b
church 2 :: (b -> b) -> b -> b
```

It really doesn't matter.

As to the type derivations, it comes down to just using the modus ponens / application rule,

```
       f   :: a -> b
         x :: a
       -------------
       f x ::      b
```

Just need to be careful renaming each type consistently so there's no type variable capture introduced at any step:

```
      succ n f x = f (n f x)
               x          ::      a
             f            :: t                              ,  t ~ ...
                      n   :: t -> a -> b
                   f      ::           b ->            c    ,  t ~ b -> c
      succ    n                       f           x :: c
      succ :: (t        -> a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
           :: ((b -> c) -> a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
```

(because final result type produced by `succ` is the same as the final result type produced by `f` -- i.e. `c`), or as GHCi puts it,

```
      succ :: ((t1 -> t) -> t2 -> t1) -> (t1 -> t) -> t2 -> t
           --   b     c     a     b       b     c     a     c
```

Comment: "The types ... all match (unify)." Hmm, well only if you tell GHC you want them to unify -- which you've done by giving signatures. Then that doesn't seem to be happening in the sig you give from GHCi. I get `succ :: ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a`.

Comment: I meant the types of the numbers themselves: `zero`, `one`, `two`... `succ` of course has a different type. I didn't specify types when I defined them in GHCi, they got derived that way as I show them. Try `:t \n f x -> f (n f x)`.

Comment: of course when it gets applied to Church numbers of type `(b -> b) -> b -> b` it becomes specialized to what you've shown.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you want `zero` to be same type as `one`. In your equation for `zero`, you don't use `f` on rhs of `->`. So the compiler doesn't know what type to infer. In your equation for `one`, you want `f x` (its result) to be same type as `x` (the result from `zero`). But you're not getting that either. It's easiest to give signatures, but failing that use `asTypeOf`.

In the equation for `succ`, you want its result to be same type as `f x`, same type as `x`.

> Can you also show me how to derive its type manually?

OK let's achieve the above using `asTypeOf`. Then you can use `:t` to find the types ...

```
zero = \   f x -> (x `asTypeOf` f x)
one  = \   f x -> (f x `asTypeOf` x)
succ = \ n f x -> (f (n f x)
                 `asTypeOf` f x `asTypeOf` x)
```

(I've used the correct definition for `succ`, per @LambdaFairy.)

Note that Church numerals are framed in the untyped lambda calculus -- that's what wikipedia is showing. As you get into more exotic functions over them (like addition or predecessor), you'll find that Haskell is a typed lambda calculus, and GHC will barf/you'll hit the dreaded monomorphism restriction. Then `asTypeOf` can't help you; you must resort to type signatures (of higher-rank).